# Использование Scrypt и Bcrypt C#

Tags: c#, .net, безопасность, хеширование, mono

Как использовать Scrypt или Bcrypt  в C#. Прошерстил несколько сайтов и форумов, но не вижу никаких объяснений, как скачать и установить библиотеку для Scrypt  и Bcrypt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Выбрать установку нугет пакетов]

[image: нужный пакет]

Пользовать так

```
string passwordHash = BCrypt.HashPassword("my password");
```

Вся документация доступна [здесь](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net).

Comment: Только немного настораживает метка [tag:mono] на вопросе.

Comment: @Qwertiy я на нее не обратил внимания, да. По крайней мере, ответ разъяснит как можно установить пакет в свой проект.

Comment: @Bulson да, вопрос о mono, но дальше я сам разберусь. спасибо!

Comment: @Bulson Только вот, как я понимаю, одно и то же слово хэшируется по-разному и встает вопрос, а для валидации этот алгоритм вообще подходит? Например, в MD5 я мог сохранять хэш  в файл и проводить проверку, сравнивая введенный хэш с тем что лежит в файле. Здесь так не выйдет?

Comment: Если бы зашли по ссылке, которую я давал в ответе, то прочитали бы про `BCrypt.Verify("my password", passwordHash);`. Лично я сам никогда не пользовался данной библиотекой, так что вам самому придется читать документацию. Обычно к паролю подмешивают, т.н. "соль" и сохраняют эту соль в отдельный столбец базы данных, наряду с полученным хэшем, а когда надо проверить пароль, извлекают эту соль и подмешивают к тому, что ввел юзер, вычисляют хэш и сверяют с тем, что есть в базе. В этой же библ. соль вычисляется самостоятельно, как я понял, короче читайте доки.

Comment: Соль подмешивают к паролю для того, чтобы в случае если разные пользователи сохранили одинаковые пароли, то хэши бы у них различались, а еще для того, чтобы исключить быстрый подбор паролей по заранее вычисленным хэшам для самых распространённых слов используемых в качестве паролей.

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо за ответы. Предлагаю посмотреть реализацию программы, которая бесконечно проверяет хэши на совпадение и выводит результат в виде булевского значения. Программа не имеет смысл, просто разобрался и представляю свое решение(надеюсь на критику!).

Answer (score 2):

В monodevelop на ubuntu делается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А используется так:

```
try
        {
            string pass = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(Console.ReadLine());

        }catch(Exception e){
            Console.Write(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот реализация создания и верификации хэшей! (Критикуйте)
Чтобы это работало, нужно сделать то, что на скриншотах выше. Прграмма не имеет смысла просто реализация.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace myself
{
    class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Select();
    }
    static void Func()
    {
        try
        {
            string txt = "";
            Console.Write("Type text - ");
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo j = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (j.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    txt += j.KeyChar;
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            }
            string password = 
            BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(txt.Trim());
            File.WriteAllText("pass", password);
            Select();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }
        Verify();
    }

    static void Verify()
    {
        try
        {
            string key = "";
            Console.Write("Type text to check - ");
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo i = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    key += i.KeyChar;
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            }
            bool check = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(key.Trim(), File.ReadAllText("pass"));//булевская переменная для проверки
            if (check == true)
            {
                Console.Write("true\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("false\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
        Verify();
    }

    static void Select(){
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists("pass"))
            {
                Func();
            }
            else
            {
                Verify();
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Почему прием строки из консоли такой страшный? Почему нельзя просто string line = Console.ReadLine(); ?

Comment: @aa_talanin так можно скрыть символы. Если есть другое решение то хотел бы узнать как это сделать лучше.

Comment: Как вы сами вверху написали, программа не имеет смысла и предназначена исключительно для тестирования. Не вижу смысла в таком случае прилагать усилия для сокрытия символов. Впрочем, ваше право.

Comment: Вот мой [пример](https://yadi.sk/d/n9TMQzNR3Z5Mp6).

Comment: @aa_talanin Понимаю, что льщу себе безбожно, но, возможен вариант, что кто-то возьмет такое решение и использует в своем проекте(это вряд ли, знаю) и там будет так как вы предлагаете. Придется искать решение(не первое в поиске), а здесь все сразу есть. в Проекте Bulson-а(https://yadi.sk/d/n9TMQzNR3Z5Mp6), используется похожее решение скрытия символов, только он предлагает использовать StringBuilder(). А вот для имени пользователя вполне подойдет то, что вы предлагаете.

Comment: @Bulson Так как я новичок в этой теме, все это(в вашем решении), кажется мудреным. Но я постараюсь разобраться(как говорится - Учится нужно у тех, кто больше знает - Или так не говорится, хз).

Comment: @Bulson Разобрался с такой системой обращений к файлам. Оказывается все просто.